# Why does a single Yubico show as multiple devices, what's the difference between hid-generic and input?

Tags: usb, udev, input, usb-device, yubikey

When I plug in my Yubikey it shows as,

```
usb 1-1: new full-speed USB device number 46 using xhci_hcd
usb 1-1: New USB device found, idVendor=1050, idProduct=0407, bcdDevice= 5.12
usb 1-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
usb 1-1: Product: YubiKey OTP+FIDO+CCID
usb 1-1: Manufacturer: Yubico
input: Yubico YubiKey OTP+FIDO+CCID as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-1/1-1:1.0/0003:1050:0407.006A/input/input93
hid-generic 0003:1050:0407.006A: input,hidraw0: USB HID v1.10 Keyboard [Yubico YubiKey OTP+FIDO+CCID] on usb-0000:00:14.0-1/input0
hid-generic 0003:1050:0407.006B: hiddev0,hidraw1: USB HID v1.10 Device [Yubico YubiKey OTP+FIDO+CCID] on usb-0000:00:14.0-1/input1
```

Why does a Yubikey have three input devices?

```
/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-1/1-1:1.0/0003:1050:0407.006A/input/input93
usb-0000:00:14.0-1/input0
usb-0000:00:14.0-1/input1
```

What's the difference between `hid-generic` and `input`? And how does `hidraw` come into play?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Partial answer:

The `input` kernel layer is an abstraction for all possible input devices, via all possible transportation technologies. PS/2 keyboards, serial mice, USB keyboards, USB camera buttons etc. all eventually show up as input devices. Events on those devices are available via `/dev/input/event*`, and you can use `evtest` to show them. Layer on top of that (like X via `evdev` or Wayland via `libinput`) then pick up those events and make them available to (graphical applications).

On the other side of the hierarchy, most of those devices also have device files that are associated with the particular transport. An important class is HID (= Human Interface Device), these are devices (often USB) that come with a standardized descriptor ("HID descriptor") for the capabilities of the device. So the device itself tells the kernel if it is a keyboard, a mouse, a joystick, etc.; which keys or movement events it generates, to some degree how one can configure it, etc.

HID devices also always get a `/dev/hidraw*` file, where one can read the raw HID event (if necessary). Usually, if the kernel can understand the HID descriptor, these events are processed by the kernel and then made available as input-layer events.

So you need to read syslog entries like this:

```
input: Yubico YubiKey OTP+FIDO+CCID as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-1/1-1:1.0/0003:1050:0407.006A/input/input93
hid-generic 0003:1050:0407.006A: input,hidraw0: USB HID v1.10 Keyboard [Yubico YubiKey OTP+FIDO+CCID] on usb-0000:00:14.0-1/input0
```

"There's a USB HID interface of class keyboard. The kernel understands this class, it will get a `hidraw0` device file and an `/dev/input/eventX` (probably X=93) device file. The `hid-generic` kernel module detected this, and called the `input` kernel layer."

```
hid-generic 0003:1050:0407.006B: hiddev0,hidraw1: USB HID v1.10 Device [Yubico YubiKey OTP+FIDO+CCID] on usb-0000:00:14.0-1/input
```

"There's a USB HID interface with a class that is not understood by the kernel. As it can't be forwarded to the input layer, it will get an `hiddev0` device file for generic HID events, and it will also get a `hidraw1` device file for raw HID events. The `hid-generic` module detected this."

So depending on how you count, you have not three, but two HID interfaces, each with two associated device files, for a total of four device file, of which only the input-layer device file is automatically used.

As to *why* Yubikey does it that way, only Yubikey knows. A reasonable guess is that they provide one general interface that can be picked up by any OS (the keyboard HID) and one interface for special configuration of the Yubikey, which will only be understood by Yubikey-specific software.

Comment: Damn fantastic answer. Thanks for that.

Comment: what does the kernel use to listen for keystrokes the event* device or the hidraw device?

Comment: @dirkt As far as I remember the yubico key can pose either as a specific device for storing the keys, and also some models pretend to be a keyboard to inject passwords open touching a button. Hmmm talking about that, have to buy one, been postponing it for ages.

Comment: The kernel doesn't listen on any devices - device files are for interaction with the user space. Internally, kernel modules call each other without going through device files, so e.g. other layers register in the input layer, etc.